# Transform Either types in Scala

Tags: scala, either

I have an `Either` type e.g. `Either[A, B]` but I want an `Either[X, Y]` by using two functions `A => X` and `B => Y`.
I can do that with fold:

```
val myEither: Either[A, B] = ...
myEither.fold(
  a => Left(createNewX()),
  b => Right(createNewY())
)
```

But that seems redundant to me as I have to repeat the `Left` and `Right`. I rather want something like:

```
val myEither: Either[A, B] = ...
myEither.transformToEither(
  a => createNewX(),
  b => createNewY()
)
```

which transforms an `Either[A, B]` to an `Either[X, Y]` by creating a `Left` for the result of the first function and a `Right` for the second one. What is the most scala-ish way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first way is probably the best for a one-time deal.  If you need to do this a lot, I would add an implicit `map` method to `Either` that gives you the API you want:

```
object EitherUtils {
  implicit class ImprovedEither[A, B](e: Either[A, B]) {
    def map[X, Y](fa: A => X, fb: B => Y): Either[X, Y] = {
      e.fold(a => Left(fa(a)), b => Right(fb(b)))
    }
  }
}
```

Scalaz adds a bunch of functionality to [either](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.std.either$), which might be useful if you care enough about scalaz to decipher their documentation.

However, in general you want to think of `Either` as a temporary container, occasionally useful for intermediate steps, rather than as something you want to keep around a long time.  If you find yourself wanting to operate extensively on an `Either`, that should prompt a second look to see if you can refactor it out earlier.

Comment: Feels like you are answering all my questions here, thx! Grüße aus Düsseldorf. ;)

Answer (score 2):

So you want to map left and right of either monad right? Instead of writing fancy utility methods I'd rather stick with vanilla monad transformers since Scala already provides tools to achieve what you want.

```
val myEither: Either[A, B] = ...
myEither
   .map(createNewX)
   .left.map(createNewY)
```